# I get a swift "run before self" error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I am getting a "cannot use instance member 'appearance' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available". Please do not suggest to remove appearance from the code, that will not work. I also added a self.appearence.kcirclebackround and got and error as well.

Here is where the kCircleHeightBackground cgfloat is set 
`open class SCLAlertView: UIViewController {

```
public struct SCLAppearance {
    let kDefaultShadowOpacity: CGFloat
    let kCircleHeightBackground: CGFloat 
    let kCircleTopPosition: CGFloat
    let kCircleBackgroundTopPosition: CGFloat
    let kCircleHeight: CGFloat
    let kCircleIconHeight: CGFloat
    let kTitleTop:CGFloat
    let kTitleHeight:CGFloat
    let kWindowWidth: CGFloat
    var kWindowHeight: CGFloat
    var kTextHeight: CGFloat
    let kTextFieldHeight: CGFloat
    let kTextViewdHeight: CGFloat
    let kButtonHeight: CGFloat
    let contentViewColor: UIColor
    let contentViewBorderColor: UIColor
    let titleColor: UIColor
```

`

and then i'm getting an error at "appearance.kCircleHeightBackground"

```
var appearance: SCLAppearance!

// UI Colour
var viewColor = UIColor()

// UI Options
open var iconTintColor: UIColor?
open var customSubview : UIView?



// Members declaration
var baseView = UIView()
var labelTitle = UILabel()
var viewText = UITextView()
var contentView = UIView()
// "I get an error here at appearance.kCircleHeightBackground"__________var circleBG = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: appearance.kCircleHeightBackground, height: appearance.kCircleHeightBackground))
var circleView = UIView()
var circleIconView : UIView?
var duration: TimeInterval!
var durationStatusTimer: Timer!
var durationTimer: Timer!
var dismissBlock : DismissBlock?
fileprivate var inputs = [UITextField]()
fileprivate var input = [UITextView]()
internal var buttons = [SCLButton]()
fileprivate var selfReference: SCLAlertView?

public init(appearance: SCLAppearance) {
    self.appearance = appearance
    super.init(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)
    setup()
}
```

[Image of error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh83Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

As the error mentions, you are not able to use your `appearance` property until it has been set in the initializer. Your properties are evaluated before the initializer runs, so your only option here is to move the desired customisation of your `circleBG` view into the initializer, for example your `setup()`-method.

Comment: That is one option, but not the only one.

Comment: @MartinR Oh, interesting! Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MartinR Just read the duplicate, didn't know that using lazy in this situation could resolve the issue. Cool!